# Side channel attack: Why building an eviction set is possible?

Tags: side-channel-attack, timing-attack, cpu

I'm learning about the side channel attack on the cache. I came to know that most of the attack **(EVICT + TIME, PRIME + PROBE, PRIME + ABORT**) on the cache is initiated by building an eviction set(a group of virtual addresses that map to the same cache sets) from the page table. And I also came to know that this is possible because multiple processes share the same CPU cache. So, my question is, just because of multiple processes sharing the same cache it is possible to build an eviction set from them or there is more to it?